# html table is not rendered in outlook using Python

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

Using Python, I try to render the html table and plain text in a email. But it is shown as a single text(not in a tabular format). Kindly refer below:

```
"id created_date testrun comments assignedto 1 Sept. 24, 2018 P0 , canary , , d gomathis@xyz.com"
```

But is expected to be as below: 
       Hi team,
        Please find the below mentioned tasks for today:

```
    id created_date testrun comments assignedto 
    1 Sept. 24, 2018 P0 , canary , , d gomathis@xyz.com
```

**code:**

```
def send_mail(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST['message']
        print("ewasrew"+message)
  else:
        htmltable = ''
  # os.startfile("outlook")
  SERVER = "smtp.xyz.com"
  me="gomathis@xyz.com"
  you="gomathis@xyz.com"
  msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  msg['Subject'] = "Today's task"
  msg['From'] = me
  msg['To'] = you

  text = "Hi team\nPlease find the below mentioned tasks for today:\n"
  html = message

  part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
  part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

  msg.attach(part1)
  msg.attach(part2)

  server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
  server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
  server.quit()
  return HttpResponse("Email sent")
```

## value of message is in html file.

```
<thead class="thead-light">
<tr><th>id</th>
<th>created_date</th>
<th>testrun</th>
<th>comments</th>
<th>assignedto</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> Sept. 24, 2018 </td>
  <td>  <a href="http://www.google.com"> P0 </a>, <a 
    href="http://www.google.com"> canary </a>,
      <a href="">  </a>, <a href="">  </a>
  </td>
<td>  d </td>
<td>  gomathis@xyz.com </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put it in `<table> </table>` tags

```
<table border="1">
<thead class="thead-light">
<tr><th>id</th>
<th>created_date</th>
<th>testrun</th>
<th>comments</th>
<th>assignedto</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> Sept. 24, 2018 </td>
  <td>  <a href="http://www.google.com"> P0 </a>, <a 
    href="http://www.google.com"> canary </a>,
      <a href="">  </a>, <a href="">  </a>
  </td>
<td>  d </td>
<td>  gomathis@xyz.com </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This works for me

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anand. Actually <table> tag is there in the original django html file. But that table is not coming in the message. That's why it is not working. Now I've added the table tag as string. Now it is working properly.

Comment: Now the htmltable is shown but the plain text is not shown. Can you please clarify?

Comment: using the above code, it results in receiving the htmltable alone. But I need the html table and plain text both in a body of the email.